# error occurred while bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.7) 
Using builder (3.0.3) 
Using activemodel (3.2.7) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.7) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.7) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.7) 
Using activeresource (3.2.7) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.7) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using commonjs (0.2.6) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.3) 
Installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/kapil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p286 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/home/kapil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
  --with-ruby-dir
  --without-ruby-dir
  --with-ruby-include
  --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
  --with-ruby-lib
  --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

---

this problem occurred while doing `bundle install`

Answer (score -1):

Try run `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` before bundle install, maybe it help?